# Let $A = \mathbb{N}$ and let $aRb$ mean that $b|a$...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> Let $A = \mathbb{N}$ and let $aRb$ mean that $b\mid a$.
>
> 1. Is $R$ reflexive on $A$?
> 2. Is $R$ symmetric on $A$?
> 3. Is $R$ anti-symmetric on $A$?
> 4. Is $R$ transitive on $A$?
> 5. Is $R$ an equivalence relation on $A$?

I do not know where to start on this question, any help into guiding me into the right path would be very much appreciated!

Comment: A good place to start would be writing down the definitions of reflexive, symmetric, etc

Comment: Then take your favorite pair (or triplet) of natural numbers, and see if they are a witness or not to the relation being reflexive, symmetric, transitive, etc

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! A good help, in my opinion, would be to translate this relation in plain language.

Comment: If I'm technically allowed to choose the numbers wouldn't I be easily able to either prove or disprove all the questions? @TomGrubb

Comment: @Supreme a proof must be a general statement; so a specific example won't be a proof but it may help you find a pattern which leads to a proof, or it could lead to a counter example and hence a disproof

Comment: @Supreme of course looking at a small number of examples can't prove things about *all* examples, however it would allow you to disprove some of the statements.  For example, note how $2\mid 4$ but $4\nmid 2$.  What does that tell you about whether or not $R$ is symmetric?  What does that tell you about whether or not $R$ is an equivalence relation?

Comment: As for the rest... use your definition of divisibility... $b\mid a$ means that $a$ is a multiple of $b$.  If further you have that $c\mid b$ then $b$ is a multiple of $c$.  For example how $4$ is a multiple of $2$ and how $8$ is a multiple of $4$.  Show that it follows that $a$ must be a multiple of $c$, and relate this to your question.  Similarly so for the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to start is to draw the relation $R$ for a few examples. Let's try $1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ and $6$. Here are all the edges you have to draw:

- $1$ divides $1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ and $6$, so draw an arrow from all the numbers to $1$ (including from $1$ to itself).
- $2$ divides $2, 4,$ and $6$, so draw three arrows (from $2$ to itself, from $4$ to $2$, and from $6$ to $2$.)
- $3$ divides $3$ and $3$ divides $6$
- $4$ divides itself
- $5$ divides itself
- $6$ divides itself

Once you draw all those edges you can check.

- "Reflexive" means every number has an edge to itself. Does this look true or false, for these examples?
- "Transitive" means that if there is an edge from $a$ to $b$ and from $b$ to $c$, then there's an edge from $a$ to $c$. Does this seem to be true in the picture?
- "Symmetric" means that if there's an edge from $a$ to $b$, then there's an edge from $b$ to $a$. Does it look true, for these exampls ($1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, and $6$)?

Once you decide which properties are true for $1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ and $6$, you can decide if the properties that are true here will be true for all other numbers, as well. That would be a good overall way to build intuition and to approach this problem and similar problems.

Comment: Wow great explanation, very much appreciated!

Comment: @Supreme You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by looking at some definitions. A relation $R$ (will also be denoted by $\sim$) on a set $X$ is

- **reflexive** if each element of $X$ is in relation with itself that is

$$
aRa\qquad\text{or}\qquad a\sim a,\qquad \forall a \in X.
$$

In your specific case this means that for $a\in \mathbb{N}$ we will check whether $a\mid a$. You could argue that $a=1\cdot a+0$ so we get $0$ as a rest when dividing $a$ with itself so $R$ is reflexive. Every natural number divides itself.

- **symmetric** if 
  $$
  aRb\Rightarrow bRa \qquad\text{or}\qquad a\sim b\Rightarrow b\sim a\qquad \forall a,b\in X
  $$

In your specific case this is not true, you could argue similarly as above but it may be easier to find a counterexample say $a=2$ and $b=4$. 
$$
2\mid 4\not\Rightarrow 4\mid 2
$$

- **antisymmetric** if
  $$
  aRb\qquad\text{together with}\qquad bRa \qquad \text{implies}\qquad a=b,\quad \forall a,b\in X
  $$

I think you can do this yourself.

- **transitive** if
  $$
  a\sim b\quad\text{and}\quad b\sim c\Rightarrow a\sim c, \quad \forall a,b,c\in\ X
  $$

This one is left for you as well.

- is an **equivalence relation** if $R$ is *reflexive, symmetric and transitive* at the same time.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Supreme You are welcome!